# Loading Luau script files with the C API

Tags: c++, lua, luau

I want to let a third-party develop a Lua script that runs with my C++ application. A script may contain many individual files. To make this safe I use [Luau](https://luau-lang.org/) for sandboxing. My C++ application must compile and load the third-party Luau script files as outlined in the [Roblox readme](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/README.md). I am not able to do this with more than one file.

Let us say that script file module1.luau looks like this:

```
module = require("module2")

print('started module 1')
print(module.hello())
```

Script file module2.luau looks like this:

```
local M = {}

function M.hello()
    return 'Hello'
end

print('started module 2')

return M
```

The simple C++ application (module.cpp) that loads the script files look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


#include <assert.h>
#include "/home/me/luau/VM/include/lua.h"
#include "/home/me/luau/VM/include/lualib.h"
#include "/home/me/luau/Compiler/include/luacode.h"

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

using namespace std;


int main() 
{  

    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    
    string content; 
    ifstream ifs;
    char* bytecode;
    size_t bytecodeSize = 0;
    
    
    
    ifs.open("module2.luau", ifstream::in);
    content.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                        (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
                                     
    bytecode = luau_compile(content.c_str(), content.length(), NULL, &bytecodeSize);
    assert(luau_load(L, "foo2", bytecode, bytecodeSize, 0) == 0);
    free(bytecode); 
    
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    
    
    ifs.open("module1.luau", ifstream::in);
    content.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                        (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
                                     
    bytecode = luau_compile(content.c_str(), content.length(), NULL, &bytecodeSize);
    assert(luau_load(L, "foo1", bytecode, bytecodeSize, 0) == 0);
    free(bytecode); 
    
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    
    
    

    lua_close(L);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Running the modules by themselves gives the expected result:

```
$ ./luau module1.luau
started module 2
started module 1
Hello
```

Running module.cpp gives this:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o module module.cpp -L/home/me/luau/build/release -lluauvm -lluaucompiler -lluauast -lisocline -lgtk-3 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0
$ ./module
started module 2
```

The second compile/load does not happen. The code is obviously wrong, but how?

I presume it is possible to load individual script files so that they work together with `require` in this manner. Note that there are a number of load C API functions that are available in Lua but not in Luau.

Comment: OT: do not use absolute paths in `#include`s. use the `-I` argument to your gcc invocation instead.

Comment: The luau code looks fairly straightforward. Have you tried running your program in a debugger and stepping into the luau code? You may also want to base your code on the [runFile function of luau instead](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/78798d46418f175767c4517fa5932111f0ca07f6/CLI/Repl.cpp#L604-L664)

Comment: I will get back to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on `std::ifstream::open`:

> If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function fails.

So, your program fails on the attempt to open `ifs` twice.
You need to explicitly close the first instance before opening the second one.

Comment: Thank you. A good point. I added a `ifs.close()` after both `content.assign` statements in module.cpp. Unfortunately I get the same output, that is only `started module 2`.

Comment: Does the second part work correctly if you comment out the first part `ifs.open("module2.luau"...lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);` ?

Comment: No. If I comment out the first part (all that has to do with module2.luau) I get nothing. I know that even if an error message is not displayed the reason is that the statement `module = require("module2")` returns `invalid argument #1 to 'require'`

Comment: This is because `require` in luau is not the same as in Lua.  The standard `require` was removed, and new `require` introduced, now it expects a [ModuleScript](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ModuleScript) object as argument (instead of a filename).

Comment: I replaced `module = require("module2")` in **module1.luau** with `module = script and require(script.Parent.M)`. Now it prints _started module 2 started module 1_ as expected but not _Hello_. It seems it does not find the module with the given path script.Parent.M. I have tried using the chunkname _foo2_ and various other combinations with no luck.

Comment: Probably you should install a "Module Script" somehow in the roblox studio GUI.  :-)

Comment: This is not a Roblox project in any way. It's totally independent of Roblox and their IDE. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will continue to debug and gather information.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution of sorts. First of all I drop calling **module2.luau** after compiling and loading the script, that is no *lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)*. Instead I set the chunkname *foo2* as a global. *foo2* is actually a function. *foo2()* returns a table. This table holds the function *hello*.

**module.cpp** is now this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


#include <assert.h>
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "luacode.h"


using namespace std;


int main() 
{  

    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    
    string content; 
    ifstream ifs;
    char* bytecode;
    size_t bytecodeSize = 0;
    
    
    
    ifs.open("module2.luau", ifstream::in);
    content.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                    (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    ifs.close();
                                     
    bytecode = luau_compile(content.c_str(), content.length(), NULL, &bytecodeSize);
    assert(luau_load(L, "foo2", bytecode, bytecodeSize, 0) == 0);
    free(bytecode); 
    
    
    lua_setglobal(L, "foo2");
    
    
    
    ifs.open("module1.luau", ifstream::in);
    content.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                    (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    ifs.close();
                                     
    bytecode = luau_compile(content.c_str(), content.length(), NULL, &bytecodeSize);
    assert(luau_load(L, "foo1", bytecode, bytecodeSize, 0) == 0);
    free(bytecode); 
    
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    
    
    

    lua_close(L);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

**module1.luau** is now:

```
module = foo2()

print('started module 1')
print(module.hello())
```

**module2.luau** is as before:

```
local M = {}

function M.hello()
    return 'Hello'
end

print('started module 2')

return M
```

Running gives the expected result:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o module module.cpp -I/home/me/luau/VM/include -I/home/me/luau/Compiler/include -L/home/me/luau/build/release -lluauvm -lluaucompiler -lluauast -lisocline
$ ./module
started module 2
started module 1
Hello
```

I presume this can be generalized to include any number of Luau script files, not just two. Are there better ways of doing it?